# How to reflect input of a textbox into another if the classes are the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my code to reflect the text of a textbox1 into another textbox that called textbox1a on keyup. and it is work good when they are only one.
my question is how can i reflect each textbox value if the class is the same with another?
here is my codes :

```js
$(".textBox1").keyup(function(){
   $(".textBox1").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    TextBox 1 : <input type="text" class="textBox1" class="valueEnter"></input>

    TextBox 1a : <input type="text" class="textBox1"></input>
    <br/>
    TextBox 2 : <input type="text" class="textBox2" class="valueEnter"></input>

    TextBox 2a : <input type="text" class="textBox2"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: you are not suppose to have multiple class attributes!

Comment: Check my answer, it is exactly what you need.

Comment: @inaz check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the class name of the input type of `text` and then add your logic:

```js
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function(){
   var className = $(this).attr('class').replace('valueEnter','').trim();
   $("."+className).val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    TextBox 1 : <input type="text" class="textBox1 valueEnter"/>

    TextBox 1a : <input type="text" class="textBox1"/>
    <br/>
    TextBox 2 : <input type="text" class="textBox2 valueEnter"/>
 
    TextBox 2a : <input type="text" class="textBox2"/>
</div>
```

Notice that it is `type=text` and not `type=textbox`. Since, you have two classes with `valueEnter`, i would like to modify a bit where we skip the class name `valueEnter` when we select a class for `textbox` in the JQuery code.

Comment: Down voters, explain your reason. Show some courage to comment your reason

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
  $('.' + $(this).attr('class')).val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    TextBox 1 : <input type="text" class="textBox1" class="valueEnter" />
    TextBox 1a : <input type="text" class="textBox1" />
    <br/>
    TextBox 2 : <input type="text" class="textBox2" class="valueEnter" />
    TextBox 2a : <input type="text" class="textBox2" />
</div>
```

It's `<input type="text">` not `<input type="textbox">`.

Look for the same class on `keyup`.

Hope this will help you.